# How to optimize SQL query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have the following SQL query and it fetches a very large data (> 100 millions) based upon the query, But it is taking a very long time (35 minutes), and I want to show this data on GUI upon click of a button. The problem is since so much time is being taken, my GUI timer expires before fetching the results from MySQL DB. I do not want to increase my GUI timer.

How can I optimize the query? I have already tried a lot things to optimize it.

```
select distinct sub.a,sub.b,sub.c,model.a,model.b,tac.a
  from table1 sub,table2 model,table3 tac,table4 equip
  where equip.a=sub.a
  and tac.a=LEFT(sub.c, 8)
  and tac.id=model.b_id
  and model.a like 'Airtel'
  and model.a like 'as1234';
```

Comment: Questions about query performance always require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the result of the EXPLAIN

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` to the end :)

Comment: For help with this, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: What are you trying to do with those records? Could pagination be useful?

Comment: The best place to start Ashish is to show us what you're doing to optimise it. Since you've "tried a lot of things", adding some description into the question should be easy. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing (or query optimising) service.